# Get google analytics real time data using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I Want to get google analytics real time data for active users. I have used google api client php from 
    https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=474#

```
For screenviews after setting metrics and dimensions

$metrics    =   'ga:screenviews';
$optParams  =   array('dimensions' => 'ga:screenName');

$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
try {
    $result = $service->data_ga->get(
        $GA_VIEW_ID,
        $start_date,
        $end_date,
        $metrics,
        $optParams
    );
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I am getting proper result.
I want to get realtime data but unable to get it. I have tried as below.

$metrics    =   'rt:medium';
$optParams  =   array('dimensions' => 'rt:activeUsers');

```
try {
  $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      $GA_VIEW_ID,
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $optParams);
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}

// Error  : Undefined property: Google_AnalyticsService::$data_realtime
```

Please give me solution to get real time data.

Comment: do you have beta access to the realtime api?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you checked out a very old version of the client library. Go ahead and checkout the `v1-master` branch from github:

```
git clone -b v1-master https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git
```

I would also suggest following the instructions in the [Hello Analytics API php](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) to help get you started.